# TideSDK Python get arguments with sys.argv

Tags: python, argv, tidesdk, sys

I'm trying to read the arguments passed to a Python script called with `Ti.Process.createProcess`.

When I run the following code:

> import sys
> sys.argv

I get the error:

> File "", line 2, in <module>
>
> AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'argv'

It looks like the `sys` object doesn't have an `argv` attribute.

Am I doing something wrong? any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have another `sys.py` in your python path.

Comment: You know I'm using TideSDK, right? How could I know if I have another `sys.py` in the PATH or debug it?

Comment: Not sure... You may use simple python script:

`import os

for i in os.walk("/path/to/your/Tide/SDK/"):
    if "sys.py" in i[2]:
        print "Found sys.py in folder",i[0]
        
`

Comment: Thanks for your help, I guess I found where the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

I found the error.

I was testing the code using this code:

> <script type="text/python" src="script.py"></script>

and

> <script type="text/python">
>        import sys
>        print sys.argv
>    </script>

And I received the error:

> File "", line 2, in <module>
>      AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'argv'

---

But when I run:

> var path = Ti.API.getApplication().getResourcesPath();
>   var p = Ti.Process.createProcess(['python', path + '\search_client.py', param1, param2]);
>   p.setOnReadLine(function(data){doStuff(data)});
>   p.launch();

I get the correct result.

---

So, in TideSDK, a python script has access to the `sys.argv` element only when it is excecuted as a "Process" but not when it's excecuted as a "<script>".